# Instance properties with default values in Swift: when are they called?

Tags: cocoa, swift

Say I have a class like this one:

```
class UniverseViewController: UITableViewController {

    var model = createModel()

    // blah, blah...
}
```

When exactly will the `createModel` function be called? Before the init? After it?

Answer (score 1):

It is called before init and viewDidLoad etc.

The following code:

```
struct testStruct {
    init() {
        println("testStruct")
    }
}

let tempValue = testStruct()

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    println("Coder")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("viewDidLoad")
}
```

will give us the following output:

```
testStruct
Coder
viewDidLoad
```